# Problem on number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of distinct integers vs a sum of odd integers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I found this problem while doing a few problems on partitions of an integer:

Prove that the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of distinct positive integers is equal to the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of odd positive integers.

Attempt at solution:
I tried to perform some manipulations on the generating function for the partitions of $n$ to get the latter, but could not do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this was proved by Euler.

The number of partitions of $n$ as a sum of odd positive integers is the coefficient of the $x^n$ in the expansion of :
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)(1-x^7)\dots} $$

and the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of distinct positive integers is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\dots$$

Trivially we have $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)(1-x^7)\dots} = \frac{1-x^2}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1-x^4}{1-x^2} \cdot \frac{1-x^6}{1-x^3} \cdot \frac{1-x^8}{1-x^4}\dots$
$$ = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\dots$$

Comment: I hadn't heard of this result, but it's surprising! You have about twice as many numbers at your disposal and yet you can add them in exactly the same number of ways to get the answer.

Comment: But the odd integers need not be distinct while the latter has to be.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

First note that any positive integer $k$ has a unique representation $k=op$ where $o$ is odd and $p$ is a power of 2, namely where $o$ is $k$'s largest odd factor and $p$ is $k$'s largest factor that is a power of 2.

Moreover, any positive integer $m$ has a unique binary representation and thus a unique decomposition (aside from permutation of the terms) as the sum of distinct powers of 2.

Let $\mathscr{P}_D$ be the set of partitions of $n$ into distinct positive integers, and $\mathscr{P}_O$ be the set of partitions of $n$ into odd parts.

For each partition $D\in \mathscr{P}_D$, let $f(D)$ be a partition into odd integers obtained as follows. For each part $k$ of $D$, let $k=op$ where $o$ is odd and $p$ is a power of 2. Replace this part $k$ by $p$ parts, each of size $o$. The resulting partition is $f(D)$. By construction, it is a partition into odd parts.

Suppose $D_1$, $D_2$ are two different partitions of $n$ into distinct positive integers. Then there is some part size $k=op$ where, wlog, $D_1$ has a part of size $k$ and $D_2$ does not. Then $f(D_i)$ has $m_i$ parts of size $o$ where $m_1$'s decomposition as the sum of distinct powers of 2 contains $p$ and $m_2$'s does not. Thus $m_1\ne m_2$, so $f(D_1)\ne f(D_2)$. Thus $f$ is injective, so $|\mathscr{P}_D|\le|\mathscr{P}_O|$.

For each partition $O\in \mathscr{P}_O$, let $g(O)$ be a partition into distinct integers, obtained as follows. For each odd integer $o$ which is the size of any parts of $O$, let there be $m$ parts of size $o$. Express $m$ as the sum of distinct powers of 2:
$$m=\sum_{i\in I} 2^i$$
Then for each $i$ replace $2^i$ parts of size $o$ by one part of size $2^io$. For any $o$ the $2^io$ are distinct because the $2^i$ were distinct by construction. And parts arising from different $o$ cannot have the same size $k$ because $k$ has only one representation as the product of an odd integer and a power of 2.

Suppose $O_1$, $O_2$ are two different partitions of $n$ into odd parts. Then there is some part size $o$ where $O_i$ has $m_i$ parts of size $o$, and $m_1\ne m_2$. Then $m_1$ and $m_2$ do not have the same decomposition as the sum of distinct powers of 2. So there is some $i$ where $2^i$ is in the one but not the other, and therefore a part of size $2^io$ is in one of the $g(O_i)$ but not the other. Thus $g(O_1)\ne g(O_2)$, so $g$ is injective, so $|\mathscr{P}_O|\le|\mathscr{P}_D|$.

Putting the two results together, $|\mathscr{P}_D|=|\mathscr{P}_O|$.